# How to impose Maxlength In Html.textarea?

Tags: model-view-controller

i am using HTML.TEXTAREA in my MVC2.0 application but i cant restrict the textarea to allow user to input only 255 characters.
I have also provided <% html.textarea("Name",new {@maxlength = "255"}) %> but still i couldnt achieve the target.
Please provide me any solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Verify your HTML version

In Html 4.0,
maxlength is not a valid property for TextArea.

maxLength attribute is added in HTML 5.0.(But unfortunately HTML 5.0 is quite new and not much browser support it)

For more information,
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can write java script and restrict text area size.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

       $(function () {
          $("#id").keypress(function () {
             var maxlen = 100;
             if ($(this).val().length > maxlen) {
                return false;
             }
         })
      }); 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A very easy way is to use `SubString`. Its not something that you need to bang your head for and you can write it yourself.

For Example:

```
var textAreaObject = document.getElementById("TextAreaId");
    if (textAreaObject != null) {
        var maxlength = 60; //Give the desired value for your Maxlength
        if (textAreaObject .value.length > maxlength) {
           //Substring from the entered text. Easy-peezy
            textAreaObject .value = textAreaObject .value.substring(0, maxlength);
        }
    }
```

Works everywhere and anywhere. And use this for on paste and on keypress events. Happy coding.